# pointer from one class to another

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Hello I want to point "seller" to "name"
but it gives me an error. please help. 
I get the error"name was not defined "
how can I make a method to assign seller to an Apartment?
Thank you

```
class Person {
    public:
        friend class Apartment;
        Person() {
          cout << "~ ";
        }//constructor
        string name = "Mr.Smith\n";
        string TelNumber = "01";
        int age = 0;
};


class Apartment {
    public:


        string Address = "jyu";
        double Area = 74.0;
        double Price = 320.0;
        int numberOfRooms = 3;
        //string name = "d";
        string *Seller = &name;
        //Apartment(string *Seller = null) {

        //}
        // constructor for seller
         Apartment () {
            string *Seller=nullptr;
         }
       // Apartment::Apartment();
};
```

Comment: "but it gives me an error." We are not mind-readers.

Comment: @tkausl: I knew you'd say that.

Comment: Which `name`? Every object of type `Person` will have another name.

Comment: You should move `Seller` field initialization to constructor and supply a pointer there. Also note that right now inside of constructor you are declaring a local variable with the same name for no reason.

Comment: You need a `Person` object if you want to point to its `name` member (not likely the best design tbh).

Comment: I add the error. 
please show me by code :|

Comment: You probably want an apartment to have a pointer to a `Person` instead, not just its name.

Comment: BTW: I don't think there's a place in the world where newline can be part of a person's name. It does bring back memories of [little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/), thogh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I add the error. please show me by code

Well, at the time I wrote this answer, still a promise... Anyway, the compilation error you mention likely is the one provoked by this line:

```
string* Seller = &name;
```

Explanation: You try to refer to some variable called `name`. The way you wrote the code, this would initialise the pointer to a class member variable of class appartment (`this->name`), which does not exist, though, as you commented it out. But even if it existed, it would not be the string object you desired, as you wanted a pointer to the seller's name, not the appartment's name...

Then, there are quite a lot of things that are – uhm – let's just say 'unconventional'...

First, you only have public members in your `Person` class – so why would you need any friend classes at all??? Even if you make the members private, you should not make `Appartment` a friend. Instead, provide appropriate public getters. Friendship provides access to private members, and typically these two friends then are very closely related one to another. Imagine you have one class `X` managing several instances of another one `Y`. Class `Y` shall only provide very limited access to its member, but contains some management data that class `X` relies on. Then you would make `X` a friend of `Y` so that `X`, but no one else, can access the management data. Quite often (but far not always) this is the case if `Y` is an inner class of `X`, but still part of `X`s public interface...

OK, back to your class:

I assume you want to be able to have different persons with different names, and each having its own phone number - or possibly some having none. I further assume that you do not want these contents to be changed by *anybody*. So: set them in the constructor and make them private:

```
class Person
{
    std::string name;
    std::string phoneNo;
public:
    Person(std::string name, std::string no = "")
        : name(name), phoneNo(no)
    {
          std::cout << "~ ";
    }
};
```

I left out `age` - actually, prefer the birth day instead: The age not only *can*, but *will* change for sure (unless you are programming some game of which the play time is shorter than a year or people simply do not age in...). By using birth day, you do not need to update your person regularly and can calculate the age whenever needed. Oh, and don't add comment's like `constructor` - every minimally experienced C++ programmer is able to recognise a constructor just by seeing a function with no return value with the name of the class - so you are just spoiling your code.

OK, quite likely, you need to *read* the person's members, so we yet need some getters to the *public* section of your class:

```
std::string getName() { return name; }
// or alternatively:
std::string name() { return m_name; }
```

I personally prefer the second variant (only a matter of taste, though!), but that requires renaming the member variable (I chose `m_name`, could as well have been `_name` or `name_` or (*almost!*) what ever you like; `_Name`, though, would have been reserved: any identifier starting with underscore followed by upper case letter is as well as any one with two subsequent underscores).

Now you can construct your person's like this:

```
Person smith("Mr.Smith", "01");
Person me("Aconcagua"); // no phone number; did you notice the default parameter?
```

The apartment is now quite similar:

```
class Apartment
{
    std::string _address;
    // all the other members

    std::string* _seller;
public:
    Apartment(std::string address, /* and other ones as needed! */);

    // getters (and setters?) as needed

    std::string* seller() { return _seller; }
    void seller(Person* person) { _seller = &person->_name; } // big oops!!!
};
```

Aha, not you got me... This way, the apartment *would* need private access to the person (or person another getter returning the pointer...). Before trying to fix that, I ask you, however: Why would you want to just store the name and not the entire person instead? By storing the pointer, you always get the name via the person's getter, but you additionally have access to all the other information of the person whenever needed... Then you should ask yourself yet another question: Is it relevant that every apartment has a seller or do apartments exist without one? In the latter case, you *can* add the person to the constructor as parameter, if it appears useful to you, in the former case, you *should* (and check, if the parameter is `nullptr`, and if so, e. g. throw some exception...).

I assume now that you can apply this change yourself, so no further code example...

But still some thoughts about organising your data: person's names and addresses consist of different sub-parts, such as forename(s!) and surename or street, house number, post code, city and potentially country (code + name?). Now imagine how ugly it gets if you wanted to search for all appartments e. g. in Neu-Ulm (city in Germany - guess, I live there...). You now would have to *parse* all addresses in your application - if you have city as a separate member, you can just do string comparisions. One step further: if you manage your cities as separate objects, you reduce the search to simple pointer comparisons - on the one hand, very efficient, on the other, you avoid problems accompanied by the redundancies you introduce by storing the cities' names (large database, and in there, you find all of these: "Neu-Ulm", "Neuulm", "New Ulm", "new Ulm" - just because different users entered the name differently...).